# What is meaning of this line of code in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am a little bit confused with this line of hello world kotr code written in Kotlin.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
```

what is code is doing here in the above line?

full code for reference

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    }

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("HELLO WORLD! from KTOR", contentType = ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's calling the main loop of the netty servlet so it starts handling incoming http requests

It's equivalent to

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
}
```

Or

```
import io.ktor.netty.EngineMain
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    EngineMain.main(args)
}
```

So you could say it literally starts the server, otherwise it would be your good-old CLI program with a main function